# Alert function is not responding

Tags: php, alert

What I'm doing wrong? I want to show an alert function or message, but it does not work:

```
echo"<nm>".ucfirst($sd->fname)."&nbsp;".ucfirst($sd->sname)."<input type='button' id='$sd->id' value='Add Friend'  style='float:right';' onclick='alert(\'Clicky!\')'/><br></nm>";
```

When I view the source, it looks like below

```
clicky!\')'="" onclick="alert(\" ;'=""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with the quotes / double quotes.

```
echo "<nm>".ucfirst($sd->fname)."&nbsp;".ucfirst($sd->sname).'<input type="button" id="'.$sd->id.'" value="Add Friend" style="float:right;" onclick="alert(\'Clicky!\');" /><br></nm>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`echo ("<a href='#' onclick='alert(\'Clicky!\')>" . ucfirst($sd->fname) . " " . ucfirst($sd->sname) . "</a>");`

Comment: actually I'm doing this through Ajax, trying to make ad friends button  echo"<nm>".ucfirst($sd->fname)."&nbsp;".ucfirst($sd->sname)."<input type='button' id='$sd->id' value='Add Friend'  style='float:right';' onclick='alert(\'Clicky!\')'/><br></nm>";